# Hugo academic delete favicon

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am building a personal website with the Academic theme for Hugo, and I was wondering if there is a way to delete the favicon. I've tried deleting the .ico file itself but it is still appearing on the website.

Comment: If you're talking about https://themes.gohugo.io/academic/, from the looks of it, I can see that you can change the image at `assets/images/icon.png`. So, remove that file, or place a transparent image there or search for references of that in the code and remove those.

Comment: That is what I've done, I deleted the image in the given folder and that doesn't work... maybe should I delete it from the template itselft ? but where ?

Comment: You're better off asking it to the theme creator then rather than on Stack Overflow. If many people use it, that question might have already been asked and answered. I found a GitHub issue: https://github.com/wowchemy/starter-academic/issues/77, that leads to their docs: https://wowchemy.com/docs/customization/#website-icon. It still has the same answer that you have already tried. So, the best bet would be to set a transparent PNG.

Comment: Are you rendering it locally? If so, after deleting a file, you should delete the `/public` directory before rebuilding.